# Is it a felony or crime to publish prices of supermarkets on our website?

Tags: advertisements, google

As you know, we all shop at supermarkets and their price tags are public for people. I've seen some websites that publish the prices of three different supermarkets, and I've seen Google Adsense ads on these sites.

My questions are:

- Are supermarket prices considered as special information that is forbidden to publish? Is it a felony or crime to publish prices of supermarkets on our website?
- Is it possible to gain income with Google Adsense by this way?

Comment: If you are thinking of actually doing this then you'll certainly want the opinion of a qualified lawyer in the jurisdiction where the supermarkets are operating.  If you're trying to prepare yourself for a conversation with a lawyer, which is certainly a good idea, you might consider making the question here hypothetical, so it isn't closed, and mentioning your jurisdiction of interest.

Comment: You would also need to understand the terms of Google Adsense to know if you could do it or not as those terms are different then the law.

Comment: If you're scraping a supermarket website for prices, that could be against their terms of use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not illegal to publish prices which are publicly displayed. They have too little creative content to be copyrighted and they aren't trade secrets since they aren't secret.

Comment: Thank you very much.  But I am still wondering if advertisement income is legal in this situation. (Can advertisement income be get via publicly displayed prices?)

Comment: @SukruAraci The question asked was very different, "Is it possible to gain income with Google Adsense by this way?" It is not illegal to make advertising income from reporting someone else's prices, but whether or not Google Adsense would permit it depends upon their policies.

Comment: I understood, thank you very much.